# How do I add a red dot on a specific part of a 3D model?

Tags: modeling

I have a 3D model of a face and would like to add red dots (think of it as if they are pimples but flat) onto the model in specific locations.

[image: Here's the 3D model I am working on]

Comment: For some reason, you don't just want to paint them into the texture?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best answer might depend on the purpose of your red dots. My answer assumes that the red dots are to be a permanent part of the skin texture used in your material i.e. skin blemishes, as you have suggested. I am also assuming you are using an image texture as part of the model's material.
There are a couple of ways to approach this.

Approach 1. If you are good at texture painting, you could apply the dots directly in Blender using  Texture Paint mode. However, texture painting is tricky, and if you paint on your original texture, and you don't like the results, you will have ruined it.

Approach 2. For more control, I would edit the texture in a photo editing program such as Gimp as follows: (Don't forget to save your work and avoid saving over original textures, in case you don't like your results)
Process:

1. Open your skin texture in an image editing program that uses layers. Gimp is free and uses layers.
2. Export the model's UV map: In edit mode in the UV editor, select your model and choose UV, Export UV map from the header in the UV editor window. Save it to your hard drive with where you can find it. Make sure you give it a sensible name, like Name of Material_UV.png.

3 Add the UV map as a layer to the image document. Put the UV layer above the texture layer, and scale it to the same scale as the texture layer. To see the texture layer below, set the opacity of the UV layer to something like 50 percent in the layers panel.

4. Add a new transparent layer to your image document between the UV layer and the texture layer.
5. Paint your dots on the transparent layer, using the UV map as a guide for positioning the dots.
6. When finished, hide the UV layer and export the image as a .png file. Upload it to Blender and add it to your material to check your work.

Tip: If you have difficulty placing the dots where you want them, you could always add a new temporary material to your model, and use the UV map as the material texture. This will show you where the lines on the UV map are actually on the model. Sometimes, when I am editing a texture, I import a copy of texture with the UV map superimposed on it just to see where my work actually shows up on the model.
Finally, whatever you do, don't save over any of your original textures. Best to put copies in a second folder for editing, and work in that folder, in case you make mistakes. Make sure you use a sensible document naming convention to keep track of your progress.
Have fun

Answer (score 1):

Is the following what you're trying to do?

You have a material on your surface.  In Edit mode, cut new edges to define the area to be filled with red. In the picture below, I've moved vertices, but that'll muck up your UVs so just cut new edges without moving them.  Select the area to be assigned the Red Dot material. Create a new material slot by clicking on the + sign and create the red material. Click on Assign.  Then you can come out of Edit mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a material driven by an empty as below:

[image]

Note the use of the empty in object parameter of the [texture coordinate node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html#texture-coordinate-node). In the gif below, there is a [shrinkwrap constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/relationship/shrinkwrap.html#shrinkwrap-constraint) added to it.

While optional, it helps to more easily snap the empty to the surface of suzanne, and keep the dot on the surface.

[image]